# Title not centre aligned vertically in the ion-header-bar

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

[image]

As can be seen from the screenshot above, the title appears fine using a *blank* template, but it is not aligned properly on the vertical axis with more margin beneath than above. I am aware that this can be fixed with CSS however I am wary of fixing it this way as it may affect devices with smaller screens. (This screenshot was taken on a One Plus One : 1920 x 1080 resolution)

Is there a way to fix this small error across the board?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this CSS code for Header-Bar Title

```
.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 10px;
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 43px;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 44px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you increased header you have to increase line-height as well.

For example if you did following:

```
.bar-header{
  height: 50px!important; 
}
.has-header{
  top:50px; 
}
```

you would need to add this as well so that title gets centered horizontally and vertically:

```
.bar-header .title {
    vertical-align: middle!important;
    text-align: center!important;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```